# How to use \simeq in equation?

Tags: equations

I need to use `\simeq` in an equation, but my code is not workin':

```
\begin{equation}\label{m-step}
P(t) \simeq {\sum_{g\in G} {\sum_{f\in F} P(t|f,g)
\end{equation}
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can highlight code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl + K, or clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field.

Answer (score 10):

You have some unnecessary braces before the `\sum`s. Remove these and it works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{m-step}
P(t) \simeq \sum_{g\in G} \sum_{f\in F} P(t|f,g)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, I'm cracked up... thanx a lot!